# Windows 10 tablet wakes up on touchpad or keyboard input

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, sleep, touchpad, wake-up

I am pretty sure I've digged through most of the available threads regarding this issue, and yet none provided a working solution.

I have ticked off the "Allow device to wake PC from sleep" option in mouse and keyboard settings. Upon checking wake_armed devices in command prompt, no devices are listed. The same goes for waketimers. What is even more awkward is that "lastwake" returns Wake History Count - 0. I've also tried reinstalling the touchpad, keyboard and HID controller drivers together with updating the BIOS.

Any suggestions on what might be the problem? Thank you for all your help.

Comment: If you succeed in preventing wakeup as you want how will you wake your tablet?

Comment: Preferably with the power button. The reason I don't want the keyboard or touchpad to wake the tablet is because they turn it on when the lid is closed (it's a convertible-sort of thing) and the keys/touchpad is pressed accidentally.

Edit: I've just run "powercfg /a" in the command prompt and it seems that my device only supports S0 state, so it's not really sleep mode of any kind, that's why disabling the devices from waking the tablet does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Like in my laptop, your keyboard is probably on USB instead of I2C and that's why it is treated as an external one. Consequently, looking at this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby-wake-sources#input-devices-1 I'm afraid it's just the way it is and we can't change it.

I have the same problem and have managed to solve it but only for a short time by creating a Recovery Drive, reinstalling Windows from it and then doing a factory reset. It only worked before the first restart so it's definitely not a good solution. I did this twice.